# How can I convert latitude and longitude coordinates to x and y with spatial Reference wkid:102100

Tags: node.js, geometry, coordinates

Is there any way to convert latitude and longitude coordinates into x and y with spatial reference wkid:102100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take `proj4js` package to transform coordinates from 4326 (lat/long) to 3857 (formerly known as 102100).
EPSG:4326 and EPSG:3857 are already defined in this library.

```
proj4(proj4('EPSG:4326'),proj4('EPSG:3857'),[2,5]);
```